# Are there any ongoing costs for cartthrob & what upgrades do you get?

Tags: cartthrob, upgrade, bug

This is more of a sales question about CartThrob, but as we're unable to get through to their offices at the moment I thought I'd ask here.

Basically we want to know if after a year or so we'll get some sort of un-expected renewal request from mightybigrobot. I think the answer is almost certainly no but need to double check.

Secondly, does anyone know what sort of patching, updates, new versions we're to expect with cartthrob?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you're unable to get through to their company for a sales question should be a red flag, imo.

However, as far as I know, there are no renewal costs involved with CartThrob.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no ongoing licensing costs for CartThrob. It's a one off purchase for the software.

I think they also offer telephone support packages now which I would imagine would be an annual cost.

Answer (score 0):

They offer paid phone support at $120/hr: http://paidsupport.mightybigrobot.com

For updates, see  http://cartthrob.com/docs/pages/change_log/index.html

Comment: So are the updates for cartthrob free of charge? I assume that minor version updates are eg 2.4 -> 2.5?